# How to link image in components in vue?

Tags: vue.js

My Vue project structure is:-

```
|-public
|   |-symbol
|       |-smally.JPG
|-src
|  |-components
|      |-Header.vue
|-App.vue
```

`Header.vue` contains :-

```
<template>
   <ons-page>
        <div class="toolbar">
            <div class="toolbar__left">
                 <img src="./public/symbol/{{HeaderImage}}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ons-page>
</template>
<script type="text/javascript">
export default{
    name:'Header',
    props:['HeaderImage']
}
</script>
```

while `App.vue` contains,

```
<template id="main-page">
    <Header HeaderImage="smally.jpg"/>
</template>

<script>
  import Header from './components/Header.vue'

  export default {
     name: 'app',
     components: {
       Header
      }
  }
</script>
```

It's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to put `./public/`

```
<img :src="'symbol/' + HeaderImage"/>
```

Comment: Maybe because the filename is `smally.JPG` while the value of `HeaderImage` is `smally.jpg`.

Comment: It's not working because if `:src` bind if the whole value is variable. say if `HeaderImage`  has `symbol/smally.jpg` but in my case it's not working

Comment: Check the updated code. I completely forgot about data binding.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new folder in `src` named with `assets`
2. Put your image into `assets` folder
3. Change `<img src="./public/symbol/{{HeaderImage}}"/>` to `<img :src="'~/assets/' + HeaderImage"/>` in your `Header.vue` file